# Getting list of anchor href attributes and text values in specific element

Tags: javascript, loops, hyperlink, extract

```
<li class="bottom">
  <a role="menuitem" aria-haspopups="true" href="/myshop.php">Your Shops</a> &raquo;
  <ul role="menu" class="menu-dropdown" id="menu-sub-shops">
    <li><a href="/myshop.php?shopid=300101">A</a> (<a href="/myshop.php?shopid=300101&act=quickstock">qs</a>)</li>
    <li><a href="/myshop.php?shopid=300739">B</a> (<a href="/myshop.php?shopid=300739&act=quickstock">qs</a>)</li>
    <li><a href="/myshop.php?shopid=300078">C</a> (<a href="/myshop.php?shopid=300078&act=quickstock">qs</a>)</li>
    <li><a href="/myshop.php?shopid=300591">D</a> (<a href="/myshop.php?shopid=300591&act=quickstock">qs</a>)</li>
    <li><a href="/myshop.php?shopid=306981">E</a> (<a href="/myshop.php?shopid=306981&act=quickstock">qs</a>)</li>
    <li class="bottom"><a href="/myshop.php?shopid=300232">F</a> (<a href="/myshop.php?shopid=300232&act=quickstock">qs</a>)</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

```js
var t1 = document.getElementById("menu-sub-shops");
for (var i = 0; i < t1.length; i++) {
  var t2 = t1[i].getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (var j = 0; j < t2.length; j++) {
    var t3 = t2[j].getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var k = 0; k < t3.length; k++) {
      eval("var shopid" + k + " = " + t3[k].attributes['href'].value);
      console.log(t3[k].attributes['href'].value);
    }
  }
}
```

I’m trying to get the links with the associated names to no avail.
Output I’m trying to get:

> A - /myshop.php?shopid=300101 
>   B - /myshop.php?shopid=300739 
>   C - /myshop.php?shopid=300078 
>   D - /myshop.php?shopid=300591 
>   E - /myshop.php?shopid=306981

[My JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ah82aan1/3/).

Comment: So, those *aren’t* the links associated with the names? Also, nothing good comes of `eval`; have you considered using an array for whatever it is you’re doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) or [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).

If you add a class to your links you can distinguish one from a pair easily.

```
<ul role="menu" class="menu-dropdown" id="menu-sub-shops">
    <li><a href="/myshop.php?shopid=300101" class="pickme">A</a> (<a href="/myshop.php?shopid=300101&act=quickstock">qs</a>)</li>
    <li><a href="/myshop.php?shopid=300739" class="pickme">B</a> (<a href="/myshop.php?shopid=300739&act=quickstock">qs</a>)</li>
</ul>
```

Now your code becomes

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("#menu-sub-shops a.pickme");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var text = links[i].text;
    var href = links[i].href;
}
```